# Apollo-server hide graphql ui in production

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I've been searching for an explanation of this. The question is kind of "basic" so I was hopping to find the solution quickly, but I haven't.

I want to hide the graphical ui in production server so anyone can't see my queries, but I can't. I don't have problems to figure it out how to have different environment variables in local and in production. I searched in the documentation but I can't find the way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable UI you can configure using `playground: false`

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/testing/graphql-playground/

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema, 
  introspection: false,
  playground: false,
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I was missing this keyword "playground". Better googler, better programmer...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are not setting the NODE_ENV=production.

In development, Apollo Server enables GraphQL Playground on the same URL as the GraphQL server itself (e.g. http://localhost:4000/graphql) and automatically serves the GUI to web browsers. When NODE_ENV is set to production, GraphQL Playground (as well as introspection) is disabled as a production best-practice.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone using Apollo Server 4 - the following plugin needs to applied: ApolloServerPluginLandingPageDisabled() - as playground has been removed from the config.